# What is _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY?

Tags: c++, g++

I was going through the source of some of the standard headers included with gcc (in `/usr/include/c++/` ) and found the following at the top of every header:

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
```

What exactly is `_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a preprocessor macro. And is defined as:

```
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY
#define _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(V) __attribute__ ((__visibility__ (#V)))
#else
#define _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(V) 
#endif
```

So if `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY` is true then in your case it will expand to:

```
__attribute__ (( __visibility__ ("default")))
```

else if `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY` is false it will do nothing.

The `__visibility__` attribute is used for defining the visibility of the symbols in a DSO file. Using "hidden" instead of "default" can be used to hide symbols from things outside the DSO.

For example:

```
__attribute__ ((__visibility__("default"))) void foo();
__attribute__ ((__visibility__("hidden"))) void bar();
```

The function `foo()` would be useable from outside the DSO whereas `bar()` is basically private and can only be used inside the DSO.

You can read a bit more about the `__visibility__` attribute here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility